# Error Code: 1064 in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I created a procedure that is supposed to do some operation but every time I call it, mysql comes out with an error, which I have not clue what it means. I have tried to understand it in vain, here 's the table structure which the stored procedure where made to do an operation on it:

```
CREATE  TABLE `recruitment`.`job_seeker` (
    `user_id` INT Null ,
    `fname` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `lname` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `mname` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `gender` VARCHAR(10) Null ,
    `dob` DATE Null ,
    `marital_status` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `address` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `city` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `nationality` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `phone` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `mobile` VARCHAR(45) Null ,
    `degree_id` INT Null ,
    `education` VARCHAR(100) Null ,
    `experience` VARCHAR(250) Null ,
    `other` VARCHAR(250) Null ,
    `job_target` VARCHAR(250) Null ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ,
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id` ASC) ,
    INDEX `degree_id` (`degree_id` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `recruitment`.`user_authentication` (`user_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `degree_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`degree_id` )
    REFERENCES `recruitment`.`degree` (`degree_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Here's the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createSeekerProfile`(in userName varchar(45),
    in fn varchar(45),in mn varchar(45), in ln varchar(45),
    in gender varchar(6),in nationality varchar(45),
    in ad varchar(45),in city varchar(45),in phone varchar(15),in mob varchar(15),

    in   maritalStatus varchar(45), in degId int, in educ varchar(100),
    in exper varchar(250), in other   varchar(250),
    in dob date,in jtarg varchar(250))
    begin
    declare returned_ID int;
    set @dyn_que = CONCAT('select user_id into @returned_ID
    from user_authentication where user_name =  ? ');
    prepare s1 from @dyn_que ;
set @usn = userName;
execute s1 using @usn ;

set @dyn_update =CONCAT('update job_seeker set fname =',fn,', lname = ',ln,' ,mname = ',mn,' ,
nationality =',nationality,',address =',ad,',city =',city,',phone=',phone,',
mobile =',mob,', gender = ',gender,',other =',other,',
degree_id =',degId,', job_target=',jtarg,', dob =',dob,', education =',educ,',
experience=',exper,', marital_status=',maritalStatus,' where user_id =@returned_ID');
prepare s2 from @dyn_update;
execute s2;
end
```

Whenever I call the procedure through:

```
call createSeekerProfile('realsilhouette','robert','marie','david','male'
,'earthal','an address here','capital of earth','012178152',
'1111111111','single',2,'engineering','looking forward','determined',
'2008-7-04','Oracle CEO')
```

I get an awful error which is:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address here,
city =capital of earth,phone=012178152,
mobile =1111111111, gender' at line 2
```

However when I try execute the update statement manually which is inside stored procedure, it works out so well.

new Post : 
 thanks god,finally I fixed the problem up, The problem came down to the order, all I did was just make the parameters in order, though update statement does not care about the order, as far as I know, I'm not sure, But what i am sure of is the stored procedure got created beautifully, here's the new code :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createSeekerProfile`(
in un varchar(45),
in fn varchar(45),
in ln varchar(45), 
in mn varchar(45),
in g varchar(10),
in dateOfBirth date,
in ms varchar(45),
in ad varchar(45),
in city varchar(45),
in nat varchar(45),
in ph varchar(45),
in mob varchar(45),
in degid int,
in educ varchar(100),
in exp varchar(250),
in other varchar(250),
in jtarg varchar(250))
begin

declare returned_ID int(11);

 set @dyn_que = CONCAT('select user_id into @returned_ID from user_authentication
 where user_name =  ? ');
 prepare s1 from @dyn_que ;
 set @usn = un;
 execute s1 using @usn ;


 set @dyn_update =CONCAT('update job_seeker set fname  
 ="',fn,'",lname="',ln,'",mname="',mn,'",lname ="',ln,'",
 gender ="',g,'",dob="',dateOfBirth,'",marital_status="',ms,'",
 address="',ad,'",city="',city,'",
 nationality="',nat,'",phone="',ph,'",mobile="',mob,'",degree_id="',
 degid,'",education="',educ,'",
 experience="',exp,'",other="',other,'",job_target="',jtarg,'" 
 where user_id = @returned_ID');
 prepare stm from @dyn_update;
 execute stm;
 end $$
```

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your forgot about quoting string values.

for example:

```
concat('update yourTable
set address ="',  @address, '" 
where id = 1');
```

or use function [quote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote)

Comment: but I created several stored procedures that way, after all I altered it just as you told me to, i got fresh new error :  `Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 `

Comment: huh... here is a pretty nice way to debug dynamic queries. 1) comment executing/preparing 2) do "select @your_query" 3) execute stored procedure and get a resulting query 4) execute query and take a look on your query. In this case you got the error because some input parameters were null. Please follow my steps.

Comment: I've followed all your steps, the error still exists, thanks anyway .

Comment: Off course it is... You should avoid any kind of "field=NULL". You should skip NULL values including in `concat` function conditions like `if @variable is not null then @stmt = concat(@stmt, ' AND yourfield = "', @variable, '"')`. Try to construct your dynamic query for each variable separately and join them after.

Comment: Good save, I've been staring at the same issue for some time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For me adding character ` (GRAVE ACCENT) helped. It is not a single quote (')

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE Order
( 
    Order_Id             integer  NOT NULL ,
    Order_Time           datetime  NULL ,
    Order_Status         char(50)  NULL ,
    Customer_Id          integer  NOT NULL 
)
```